# wso2 IS: Using importPolicyFromRegistry API

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I want to import policy into WSo2IS using the SOAP importPolicyFromRegistry API
I've first created 1 template policy using the wso2 editor which is working. Then I want to import copies of them by changing just the PolicyId and some attributeValue.
The ImportPolicyFromRegistry API seems to be exactly what I'm looking for,
Unfortunatly is seems that the policyRegistryPath must be set to a specific value (internal wso2 registry path).
When I try to set a place lime /tmp/mypolicy.xml I get an "index out of range -1". Looking at the wso2 java code it seems that this API is looking for a path containing CONFIG_REGISTRY_IDENTIFIER global parameter ...

If you could give me some example or guide here that would help me a lot .!!

Thanks
vpl

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I was looking for .

I finally succeeded by using your java example but sending to a dummy http address and tracing the traffic with wireskark ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns3:addPolicy xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
            <ns3:policyDTO>
                <ns1:policy xmlns:ns1="http://dto.entitlement.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">    
                <![CDATA[
                    <Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="policy-3" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="1.0">
                       <Target>
                          <AnyOf>
                             <AllOf>
                                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
                                   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">/tenant-3/*</AttributeValue>
                                   <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                                </Match>
                             </AllOf>
                          </AnyOf>
                       </Target>
                       <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="rule-31">
                          <Condition>
                             <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
                                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">turlututu</AttributeValue>
                                <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
                             </Apply>
                          </Condition>
                       </Rule>
                    </Policy>               
                ]]>
                </ns1:policy>
            </ns3:policyDTO>
        </ns3:addPolicy>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `importPolicyFromRegistry` method, It means that your policy must be in the WSO2 registry location. First,  you must upload your policy in to WSO2 registry and then you can use above method to upload policy in to the actual PDP.  You need to provide policy path as a registry resource path...  It means,  if the policy is in config registry.  policy path would be `conf:/{path to policy}`  if the policy is in governance registry, `gov:/{path to policy}`

Also, if your are creating the policy using a template policy, I guess you can use the `addPolicy` method to do it. You can find the policy administration java client from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/09/27/xacml-policy-administration/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarification on the ImportPolicyFromRegistry. So I have to us the addPolicy method. But my client is not java based, I need an example of a SOAP addPolicy request they are a lot of parameters in this request and without guidance I'm going to loose a lot of time. I've search for one on the web but could not find any. Would you have 1 example I could leverage ? Thanks very much for your support. Vpl

Comment: Hi,The reason I need the SOAP enveloppe (SOAPUI example) is because my client who will send this request eat easily SOAP message and going through the java client would be les easier ...

Comment: I've tried to setup the DEBUG level on wso2is to capture the trace but the addPolicy method parameters are not matching. I've tried also to submit the following request from SOAPUI (on the parameters who looked meaninfull) but I get a 500 internal error ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was looking for.

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="testAnd" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <Description>Test And</Description>
   <Target></Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="primary-group-emps-rule">
      <Target>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://localhost:8280/services/Customers/getEmployees</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
      </Target>
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-set-equals">
            <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="group" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example-group" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin_emps</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="deny-rule"></Rule>
</Policy>
```

With regards
Vpl